# How add relationship data?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

When i tryed save - i have null on relation column

how i can save this relation data?

Entity:

```
@Entity('project')
export class Project {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column('varchar')
  name: string;

  @Column('varchar')
  description: string;

  @Column()
  createdAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(type => User)
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  user: User|number;
}
```

Dto:

```
export class CreateProjectDto {
  readonly id: number;
  readonly name: string;
  readonly description: string;
  readonly createdAt: Date;
  readonly user: User|number;
}
```

I cant resolve this probblem, who can help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue with your entity. More than likely an issue with your query. When saving relationships, they're not automatically queried from the repository.

Take a look at this https://typeorm.io/#/undefined/loading-objects-with-their-relations

you'll notice that there is a key called `relations`. This is where you specify that you want to join your user. For example

```
import {Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';
import {Repository} from 'typeorm';
import {InjectRepository} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import Project from './project.entity';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Project) private readonly projectRepository: Repository<Project>) {}

  async findOne(id: number): Promise<Project | null> {
    return await this.projectRepository.findOne({
      where: {
        id,
      },
      relations: ['user'],
    });
  }
}
```

This should now fetch your project entity with the relation user if a user has been assigned. Hope this helps!

Comment: how to get username from the user relation. It is not directly allowing to get projectRepository.user.username. after JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projectRepository)) only it becoming a normal object.Any idea on this ?